# Why is the bytedistance 8 and not 10?

Tags: assembly, x86, byte

So i was following along at http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html and stumbled upon something which I don't quite understand:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x8000490 <main>:       pushl  %ebp
0x8000491 <main+1>:     movl   %esp,%ebp
0x8000493 <main+3>:     subl   $0x4,%esp
0x8000496 <main+6>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x800049d <main+13>:    pushl  $0x3
0x800049f <main+15>:    pushl  $0x2
0x80004a1 <main+17>:    pushl  $0x1
0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp
0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
0x80004b5 <main+37>:    pushl  %eax
0x80004b6 <main+38>:    pushl  $0x80004f8
0x80004bb <main+43>:    call   0x8000378 <printf>
0x80004c0 <main+48>:    addl   $0x8,%esp
0x80004c3 <main+51>:    movl   %ebp,%esp
0x80004c5 <main+53>:    popl   %ebp
0x80004c6 <main+54>:    ret
0x80004c7 <main+55>:    nop
```

and that is: "We can see that when calling function() the RET will be 0x8004a8, and we
want to jump past the assignment at 0x80004ab.  The next instruction we want
to execute is the at 0x8004b2.  A little math tells us the distance is 8
bytes."

I don't know how she/he got the 8 bytes. I don't see that. I'm new to gdb and also assembler but intuitively I would go ahead and calculate:
0x8004b2 - 0x8004a8 = A (hex) = 10 (dec). So I would say the distance is 10 bytes not 8. What am I missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Superficially you appear to be correct. Note that modifying the return address in the function would cause the stack adjustment right after the call to be skipped, so that would also have to be taken care of elsewhere.

Comment: Reading this same article, googled the exact math (0x8004a8 -  0x8004b2), and this was the first result. Yay SO!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the length of the jump instruction that will do the job!

A short jump requires 2 bytes and the encoded distance starts from the end of this instruction.

So byte 1 will be EBh and byte 2 will be 08h.

Comment: If you look at the link, `function` is overwriting the return address and then returning to that address. The sample on the site seems to be wrong.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I admit I didn't follow the link. I assumed the exercise was about self modifying code.